# copy SVN modified files including directory to a another directory

Tags: file, svn, unix, cut, ack

I have a list of files in my current working copy that have been modified locally. There are about 50 files that have been changed.

I am using the following command to copy files that have been modified in subversion to a folder called /backup. Is there a way to do this but *maintain* the directories they are in? So it would do something similar to exporting a SVN diff of files. For example if I changed a file called `/usr/lib/SPL/RFC.php` then it would copy the `usr/lib/SPL` directory to backup also.

```
cp `svn st | ack '^M' | cut -b 8-` backup
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It looks strange, but it is really easy to copy files with `tar`. E.g.

```
tar -cf - $( svn st | ack '^M' | cut -b 8- ) |
tar -C /backup -xf -
```

Comment: That's _exactly_ what I was looking for, many thanks. I guess for files I have added I will just have to re-run by changing the argument passed to ack to `'^A'`

Comment: To check for modified _and_ added files I am now doing this: `tar -cf - $( svn st | ack '^M|^A' | cut -b 8- ) | tar -C /backup -xf -`

Comment: And to do this on Windows from cygwin, swapping backslashes for forward-slashes: `tar -cf - $( svn st | grep "^[MA]" | cut -b 8- | sed -e "s/\\\/\\//g" ) | tar -C ./backup -xf -`

Answer (score 1):

Why not create a patch of your changes? That way you have one file containing all of your changes which you can timestamp in the name - something like `2012-05-28-17-30-00-UnitTestChanges.patch`, one per day.

Then you can roll up your changes to a fresh checkout once you're ready, and then commit them.

FYI: [Subversion 1.8](http://subversion.apache.org/roadmap.html#next-release-status) should have [checkpointing](http://subversion.tigris.org/issues/show_bug.cgi?id=3626) / [shelving](http://subversion.tigris.org/issues/show_bug.cgi?id=3625) (which is what you seem to want to do), but that's a long way off, and might only be added in Subversion 1.9.